# Form model binding Laravel / Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, laravel

Is there anny possibility when editing an entry (an update actually) with an Angular form, to populate the fields with the data already stored in the database?

In other words, can I do form model binding with Angular/Laravel?

Comment: Try [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource), [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) or [restmod](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use ngResource and when you'll get data from Laravel, then you can bind the returned JSON object as a model to your form.

```
    $scope.formDatamodel = {};

    //Suppose you will get data from Laravel here 
    var Apidata = $resource('/api/account/updateStatus').get();

    Apidata.$promise(data){

        $scope.formDatamodel = data;

    }
```

Now you will have to make ngModel binding in your form controller.

```
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="formDatamodel.password">
```

Comment: I'm not sure why u use $resource? It also works without it?

Comment: After reading the documentation, i realized that everything I have written can easily be obtained with $resource? But since I already have it this way, I'm gonna leave it like that :). Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right approch, but this is how I did it.

I get the data with the show method:
Factory:

```
            show : function(
            id
        )
        {
            return $http.get('/api/rides/' + id);
        }
```

Controller:

```
        $scope.rideEdit = {};
    var id = $stateParams.id;
    // Alles nemen van 1 record
    Ride.show(id)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.rideEdit.Dataname = data.name;
            $scope.rideEdit.Description = data.description;
            $scope.rideEdit.datetime = data.ridedatetime;
            $scope.rideEdit.persons = data.ridepersons;
            $scope.rideEdit.vertrekpunt = data.ridevertrekpunt;
            $scope.rideEdit.eindpunt = data.rideeindpunt;
        });
```

So then it displays the data.